# session id value changes

Tags: php, session

I am writing a PHP website. I have a `$_SESSION['id']` that hold the username id of a user, which I will use this value later on in my scripting. However, I notice that the ID changes as I surf the site.

Is `id` reserved in any way? Or, should I change `id` to something else?

This problem is happening whenever I click on a button several times. I am 100% sure that I'm not altering `$_SESSION['id']` beyond the initial login.

Could someone please help me understand what is happening, and how it can be fixed.

Comment: What does it change to?  Nothing?  Or does the actual value change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you already use `session_start`, if not see the other comments :P

If you have register globals on, you may be seeing behavior like that if you use the variable `$id` in your code. As a test, try:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['testing'] = 'Foo';
$testing = 'bar';
die($_SESSION['testing']);
?>
```

Reload the page a couple times. If `bar` prints out rather than `Foo`, that may be your problem. You'll probably want to make the session variable name something that is less likely to get used elsewhere, or (more correct) turn off register globals.

Comment: AMAZING! when i run ur script i got Foo, on next refresh i got bar all the time.. may you please explain this weird behavior and how i can overcome this in my code

Comment: When the script starts, `$_SESSION['id']` is filled but also `$id` is with the same thing. When you change `$id` it changes the `$_SESSION['id']`, but not until the next page loads. So generally, you don't want to use the same key in `$_SESSION` as you do a variable. Remember though, this only happens when register globals in on, and it is risky to have it on.

Comment: just add this to the config file which is included at the top of each file 
if (ini_get('register_globals') == 1)
 die("you must disable register_globals in php value for this script to function.");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `session_start()` at the very top of the page(aka before ANYTHING else).

This may be causing the screw up.

A very quick rundown as to why you need to do this:

Most of the time a session id(different from $_SESSION['id'], don't worry) is stored via cookie. The cookie values are sent via the response headers, which needs to be the first thing that is sent back to the client. So if you are outputting ANYTHING before calling session_start(), you are actually forcing php to send the response headers. This will cause the response headers to NOT contain the cookie session value, thus not being able to properly use the session.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you start the session - look at [session_start();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)