# session variable value changed

Tags: php, session

I am using session to store some data in my php website, but in some page when I fetched the data in the session is changed some times and some time its same.
I searched lots of and find some answer at

[session id value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358442/session-id-value-changes)

" if you have register globals on, you may be seeing behavior like that if you use the variable $id in your code. As a test, try:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['testing'] = 'Foo';
$testing = 'bar';
die($_SESSION['testing']);
?>
```

"

help me i searched in my php file but i dont find similar variables like session variables so what is the problem ?? 
give me some details about php session and if possible suggest good books.

> **edited :**

i have set the php.ini as all of you saying its problem of register_global off and than ckeck by using  `phpinfo();` function and check the `register_global` is off.
but after some time i logged in with my id and than at mypage menu.php accessed by me after that its changed session logged id and i logged in another account automatically.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Register_Globals by adding the following line in your php.ini file may fix this problem.

`register_globals = Off`

If you are using a Shared Web Hosting service, follow:

- If you have access to /cgi-bin folder then create your custom php.ini file inside it.
- And if you dont have access, then create your custom php.ini file in root folder.

And then add above mentioned line in php.ini file.

Adding the following line of code in your `.htaccess` file also fix your problem.

`php_flag register_globals off`

Comment: can i have to add php.ini in all dirs ?

Comment: i have uploaded it to /cgi-bin folder......will it need to add in other folders in public_html ????

Comment: you just need only one custom php.ini file. If your webserver support htaccess file, then the best solution is using .htaccess file.

Comment: webserver supports htaccess but when i put php_flag register_globals off  it give internal server error

Comment: @Mehuldabhi Check your php version and read [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals)
If still you are getting 500 - internal server error, then please contact your service provider...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using register globals so it shouldn't be an issue.

Add this line to .htaccess to disable if you have register globals running:

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

it can't be done with ini_set() at runtime so you will need to use htaccess or php.ini as in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely these days that register_globals is your problem. More likely it's to do with a) where the actual session data is being stored; and b) how the "session ID" is being transmitted from one request to the next.

The first thing to look at is [session_save_path()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php), which tells PHP where on disk to store the data that you put into the session variables.

The other part is a little more complicated, but is about how the cookie is set which lets PHP know to load the same session rather than creating a new one. You might need to look at things like the lifetime of this cookie, or the scope (domain / sub-domain / URL path) it applies to. Have a look at [session_set_cookie_params()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), and in general have a read through that section of the PHP manual to understand how sessions work.